# A Geometric Proof for a Theorem Estimating the Slope $\alpha$ of a Given Line L

Tags: elementary-number-theory, continued-fractions

We have a theorem estimating the slope a of a given line $L$.
This is done in terms of the slope of the point $P$ with coordinates $(q, p)$. The proof went through the case P is below $L$. Write up the proof for the case that $P$ is above $L$.

Here is the theorem and proof mentioned above (THE THEOREM IS TO BE THE BASIS OF MY PROOF, THE PROOF BELOW IS SIMPLY CONTEXT):

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

I have not been able to solve this problem, and struggle to start. Can someone show the steps to a solution?

Comment: The proof has already completed for all all three cases (for $\alpha>0$), above, on, and below. What else is needed to add?

Comment: The question is asking for a specific proof for the case that $P$ is above $L$.